# Save model state between viewControllers with Realm - it breaks relation

Tags: swift, realm

I use Realm in my swift project.

Here are my objects, Meal and Reaction - with a mapping of one to many:

```
enum DishType: String{
  case Breakfast
  case Second_breakfast
  case Brunch
  case Elevenses
  case Lunch
  case Tea
  case Dinner
  case Supper
  case Snack
}

class Meal : Object{
  dynamic var date: NSDate = NSDate()
  dynamic var dishType = DishType.Breakfast.rawValue

  var dishTypeEnum: DishType{
    get{
      return DishType(rawValue: dishType)!
    }
    set{
      dishType = newValue.rawValue
    }
  }

  dynamic var foodItems: String = ""
  var reactions = List<Reaction>()
}


enum Category: String{
  case Apetit
  case Energy
  case Emotion
}

enum Type: String{
  case Positive
  case Negative
}

class Reaction: Object{

  dynamic var category = Category.Apetit.rawValue
  dynamic var text: String?
  dynamic var selected: Bool = false
  dynamic var type = Type.Positive.rawValue
  .....
}
```

I need to save state from one viewController to the other. 
I select some reactions, which I have to see selected when returning to the reactions screen.

[image: saving Reaction state]

I was thinking saving into Realm, but I also have to clear all reactions state when entering a new set of data. 
When deleting from Reaction, it seems that it also breaks the relation. I have Meal objects saved (which also have a relation with Reaction).

I do not know how to distinguish between Reactions that indicate state and the ones that are in relation, from a saved Meal.

I was thinking saving Reactions for state, just in NSUserDefaults. But like this I will combine both frameworks.

What to you think? How do you save state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking saving into Realm, but I also have to clear all reactions state when entering a new set of data. When deleting from Reaction, it seems that it also breaks the relation. I have Meal objects saved (which also have a relation with Reaction).

When you make the modifications to the `Reaction` objects, these modifications will appear where ever the reactions are linked. So you likely don't want to make modifications to them unless it's a rewording. (e.g. fixing a typo "You don't want desert" => "You don't want dessert" ) Also if you delete them, they will be also deleted from `Meal` objects where they were linked.

> I was thinking saving Reactions for state, just in NSUserDefaults. But like this I will combine both frameworks.

That's not necessary. You can solve your use-case entirely by using Realm.

The solution is that you don't include an attribute `selected` in `Reaction`. Instead you just add the selected reactions to the `Meal`. In your view controller that means, that you render a cell for each `Reaction` by querying for all of them with `let reactions = realm.objects(Reaction)`.

You can then figure out whether you need to add the checkmark, by checking whether they are included in the `Meal`'s reactions like this:

```
meal.reactions.contains(reaction)
```

If a reaction for a meal is selected, you add it to the meal:

```
meal.reactions.add(reactions[indexPath.row])
```

If a reaction is deselected, you remove it from the meal:

```
meal.reactions.removeAtIndex(meal.reactions.indexOf(reactions[indexPath.row]))
```

Comment: I like your elegant solution. However, when should I add all Reactions to Realm, so that I can have those ready for my viewcontroller?

Comment: Where do they come from? I guess, they should be already there from first app launch. You could create a separate target, which setups the realm database and creates all reactions and copy that database back to your project. You can then add the .realm file to your project and make sure on first launch to copy that file from the app bundle over to the user data directory. (`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path`)

Comment: Ok, I am trying your suggestions. Thank you!